# Absolute and Sliding Caching In Redis

Tags: redis

I want to implement Absolute and Sliding Caching In Redis. Does anyone have any resource link then it will be helpful

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Redis already have many commands for this :

- [EXPIRE](http://redis.io/commands/expire) : Set a timeout on key.
- [EXPIREAT](http://redis.io/commands/expireat) : Same as previous but takes an absolute Unix timestamp (seconds since January 1, 1970).
- [TTL](http://redis.io/commands/ttl) : Returns the remaining time to live of a key that has a timeout

One important thing you have to know about Expiration on Redis : the timeout value is cleared only when the key is removed or overwritten using SET or GETSET. All others commands (INCR, LPUSH, HMSET, ...) will never change the initial timeout.

**Absolute expiration** is a native feature of Redis using EXPIRE. To implement a **sliding expiration** you simply need to reset to timeout value after each command.

A basic way to do this could be

```
MULTI
GET MYKEY
EXPIRE MYKEY 60
EXEC
```

Comment: It's been 7 years, is there still no sliding expiration in Redis?

Comment: so sad to see an industry standard caching system still does not have native sliding expiration. It is what it is.

Comment: Note that as of Redis 6.2.0 the [GETEX](https://redis.io/commands/getex/) command allows you to do this in a single command.