# Dynamically extend ttl in redis cache

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis

I have been trying to learn about spring boot with redis and I canme across [this](https://programmerfriend.com/ultimate-guide-to-redis-cache-with-spring-boot-2-and-spring-data-redis/) excellent article which pretty much explains everything. But I have been trying to find out if it is possible to dynamically reset the TTL of a cache entry by putting the cache entry back in cache every time it is fetched. For example the ttl for my cache entry is 1hr, can I keep extending it and prevent its eviction as along as it is being actively accessed.

```
@Service
public ControlledCacheService {
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "myControlledCache")
public String getFromCache() {
    return null;
}

@CachePut(cacheNames = "myControlledCache")
public String populateCache(String value) {
    return value;
}
}

.
.
.
@Autowired
ControlledCacheService controlledCacheService;
private String getFromControlledCache() {
    String fromCache = controlledCacheService.getFromCache();
    if (fromCache == null) {
        log.info("Oups - Cache was empty. Going to populate it");
        String myValue = "valueToPutInCache"
        String newValue = controlledCacheService.populateCache(myValue);
        log.info("Populated Cache with: {}", newValue);
        return newValue;
    }
    log.info("Returning from Cache: {}", fromCache);
    controlledCacheService.populateCache(myValue);  // **will calling this reset the ttl ?**
    return fromCache;
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280316/absolute-and-sliding-caching-in-redis